# moving an element in JS

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I'm learning javascript and trying to make a simple exercise : I have a text box and want control it with keyboard.
My HTML is the following (for now, I'm just trying 1 direction)

```
const myBox = document.querySelector("h1");
document.addEventListener('keydown', function (event){
    if (event.keyCode == '38'){
        myBox.style.top -= 5;
        console.log("test if it works");
    }
});
```

and my HTML is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Tuto</title>

    <style>
        h1 {
            width: 200px;
            height: 40px;
            border: 5px solid #BADA55;
            color: #A28;
            margin: 0;
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div><h1>My text</h1></div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My check test with console log works. So event listener does.
But my box doesn't move. How can I solve it and why my use of .style.top is incorrect ?

Thank you

Comment: How about adding `myBox.style.position = "absolute";` right before the line where you move the box?

Comment: _"The [`HTMLElement.style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) property is used to get as well as set the **inline style of an element**. While getting, it returns a `CSSStyleDeclaration` object that contains a list of all styles properties for that element with values assigned for the attributes that are **defined in the element's inline style attribute**."_

Comment: In this case, setting the position as "absolute' will mess up the element's initial position. I think you should use 'relative' instead.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To move an element by changing it's top value, the element can't have a static position (the default). You'll need to change the position to [`absolute`, `relative`, `fixed`, etc...](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/position?v=example).

Get the current `top`, `left`, etc... using [`Element#getBoundingClientRect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect), which will give you the correct initial value, and save you the need to parse a string. Since `top` needs to have a unit (px, em, etc..), add `px` to the changed `top`.

```js
const myBox = document.querySelector("h1");
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == '38') {
    myBox.style.top = myBox.getBoundingClientRect().top - 5 + 'px'; // parse the string to number, subtract 5, and add 'px'
    console.log(myBox.style.top);
  }
});
```

```css
h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 5px solid #BADA55;
  color: #A28;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>My text</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok thanks, in (parseFloat(myBox.style.top || 0) - 5 + 'px'), why do you use "| 0" ?

Comment: The 1st time `top` is not set, so we need a default 0. However, I didn't like it, so I've changed it to `Element.getBoundingClientRect()`, which gets the initial value correctly, and parses the number. See edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

Positions property like "top", "bottom", "left" and "right" will not work unless your element has the property "position" as "absolute" or "relative".
In that case, what you want is to add "position: relative" to your h1 style on css.

If you want to understand more about that, this can give you a headstart https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp :D

Answer (score 0):

1- you have to use **let** not *const*, because you want to change it and it is not fix;

```
let myBox = document.querySelector("h1");
```

2- you have to set your element as **absolute** position. because *top* property work not in static position

```
position:absolute;
```

3- you have to **convert** value of top position to number and then do something

```
myBox.style.top = parseFloat(myBox.style.top || 0) - 5 + 'px';
```

see my code : https://codepen.io/miladfm/pen/dRNLvw

Answer (score 0):

```js
const myBox = document.querySelector("h1");
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == '38') {
    myBox.style.top = myBox.getBoundingClientRect().top - 5 + 'px'; // parse the string to number, subtract 5, and add 'px'
    console.log(myBox.style.top);
  }
});
```

```css
h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 5px solid #BADA55;
  color: #A28;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>My text</h1>
</div>
```

(reply)
now we just need a way to prevent it from going out of bounds. think you can do that?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).