# Image not moving onclick

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I'm trying make this image move 16px every click, but it's not moving. I've tried this:

But that only moves it once. So I tried something different that I found online.

**Here is my code:**

Html:

```js
document.getElementById('player').style.left += "-16px";

function left() {
   var left = parseInt(player.style.left);
   player.style.left = (left +16) + "px";
}
```

```html
<img id="player" src="characters/prisoner-down.png"></img>
<img id="leftbtn" src="icons/left.png" onclick="left();"></img>
```

Edit: if it's useful to know, there are gonna be three more buttons for the other directions and the image I want to move is in another DIV from the image that moves it. On my editor it says that the symbol ` is invalid, so I'd like to avoid it.

Comment: `document.getElementById('player').style.left += "-16px";`

Comment: Did you style the element so it is capable of being positioned?

Comment: @epascarello I don't know what you mean exactly by that, but it can be moved so I think yes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [moving an element in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44617545/moving-an-element-in-js)

Comment: @HereticMonkey It doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: What is "It"? There are 3 answers to that question. The accepted answer has a snippet which shows it working...

Comment: @HereticMonkey I don't how I would apply the code to my code, as I think it was made for moving something different. So I don't think _any_ of the answers will work.

Comment: So you didn't try any of them, because they changed `top` instead of `left`?

Comment: @HereticMonkey No, that would be rather dumb. I tried them, and I am still trying to apply them to my code right now. It _might_ work, but it isn't working as of yet.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Non of the answers worked for me.

Comment: [Edit] your question, showing how you implemented the answers and what "doesn't work" means (are there errors? does it not do what you expect? what debugging have you done?)

Comment: I probably should've specified. This how I tried to add one of them (all the others were practically implemented the same way, just with different code in places) `const myBox = document.querySelector("player");

function left() {
   myBox.style.top = myBox.getBoundingClientRect().top - 5 + 'px'; // parse the string to number, subtract 5, and add 'px' console.log(myBox.style.top);
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function that get the direction of the translation and the number of pixels to increment, then return a function that set style.transform of the element clicked, using a closure you can update the amount of pixels to translate, try this:

```js
function transform(side, n) {
    let translatePixels = 0;

    if (side == 'right') {
        return function(e) {
            translatePixels += n;
            e.target.style.transform = `translate(${translatePixels}px)`;
        }
    }
    if (side == 'left') {
        return function(e) {
            translatePixels -= n;
            e.target.style.transform = `translate(${translatePixels}px)`;
        }
    }                              
}

const translateRight = transform('right', 16);
const translateLeft = transform('left', 16);
```

```html
<img onclick="translateRight(event);" src="https://images.rappi.com.ar/products/2311265-1622567743906.png?d=200x200&e=webp"></img>

<img onclick="translateLeft(event);" src="https://cdn.domestika.org/c_fill,dpr_auto,f_auto,h_256,pg_1,t_base_params,w_256/v1499705651/avatars/000/536/178/536178-original.jpg?1499705651" style="right: 0; position:absolute"></img>
```

Comment: After clicking a few times `transform: translate(16px) translate(16px) translate(16px) translate(16px) translate(16px) translate(16px) translate(16px) translate(16px) translate(16px) translate(16px) translate(16px) translate(16px) translate(16px) translate(16px) translate(16px) translate(16px);` I think there would be a better way lol

Comment: @epascarello you're right, i will update the answer

Comment: Is there I way I can make this move a different image from the one I'm pressing?

Comment: @CaptainYulef yes, check out my answer updated

Comment: @sonEtLumiere I made it so that it moves the img left and right, but when I press the left button then the the right (or the other way around) it jumps to where I was the the last time I pressed the button.

Answer (score 0):

Give `position` property to the `img` which you want to move.

Like `position: relative;`, `position: absolute;` etc.

By positioning them you can use `top`, `left`, `right` and `top` properties.

don't use `position: static;` on that `img` cause above property has no effect on static element.

```js
document.getElementById('player').style.left = "-16px";

function left() {
   let left = parseInt(player.style.left);
   player.style.left = `${parseInt(left+16)}px`;
}
```

```css
img{
  /*important for using left, right, top and bottom properties*/
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<img id="player" src="https://i.postimg.cc/44pXvSwD/pngwing-com.png"></img>
<img id="leftbtn" src="https://i.postimg.cc/FRkMDYvr/Pngtree-right-arrow-flat-multi-color-3777297.png" onclick="left();"></img>
```

Comment: I already had my image positioned. I tried this code but it didn't work.

Comment: @CaptainYulef Well you need to show what is different, hard for us to guess why it would not work.

Comment: @epascarello I'm not sure what is different, as far as I am aware it _should_ work, but it just doesn't.

Comment: @epascarello I disabled all the code besides what I shown you and it still doesn't work. I am confused